# (My)SQL - Count values from table in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the count of each value in a table. Problem is I need to get it out of 3 columns in that one table.

The (simplified) database table would look something like this:

```
+---------+------+--------+------+
|   Id    | Col1 | Col2   | Col3 | 
+---------+------+--------+------+
|    1    |  a   |  a     |      |
|    2    |  b   | null   |  a   |
|    3    |  b   |  b     |  c   |
|    4    |  d   |  a     |  null|
|    5    |  a   |  c     |  c   |
+---------+------+--------+------+
```

And this is the result I need:

```
+-------+-------+
|  Col  | Count |
+-------+-------+
|   a   |   5   |
|   b   |   3   |
|   c   |   3   |
|   d   |   1   |
+-------+-------+
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I also want to get the top of x-amount of rows with the highest count, even when doing an order by asc/desc on either count or col the 10 HIGHEST must be shown. I figured out that a simple limit 10 wouldn't work when I order by Count desc. Then I would get the 10 lowest values instead of the highest.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design, but UNION will get you what you want.

Comment: use a `UNION ALL` with 1 column and count in an outer query the values.

Comment: I know it's poor design but it's not my database and I'm not allowed to change anything in the database.

Comment: For the second part of your problem, I suggest you provide a more representative data set TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT. Sqlfiddle is good for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is probably a `UNION ALL` with a `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT col, COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT col1 col FROM mytable UNION ALL 
  SELECT col2 col FROM mytable UNION ALL 
  SELECT col3 col FROM mytable
)z
GROUP BY col
HAVING col IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49dd/2).

If you want it limited to the top 10 but ordered the other direction, [you can just wrap it in a subquery and order the outer one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49dd/5).

Answer (score 0):

Your original question can be solved using `union all` and then `sum` with `case`:

```
select 'a', sum(
  (case when col1 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end)+
  (case when col2 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end)+
  (case when col3 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end))
from yourtable
union all
select 'b', sum(
  (case when col1 = 'b' then 1 else 0 end)+
  (case when col2 = 'b' then 1 else 0 end)+
  (case when col3 = 'b' then 1 else 0 end))
from yourtable
...
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/355728/3)