# MySQL query to search a record in complete database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i'm searching for a SQL query to run through PhpMyAdmin to find all records in all the tables of the database that contains a given string.
till now all i've found is a query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'final_year_project_demo'
```

that returns all the tables in the schema , but i'm not efficient in SQL so not able to move any further than that.

all i need is a query that will list all the records(containing a particular string in any column) from all the tables that are listed through above code.
columns in all tables are same.

Comment: Please have a look at the approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616695/mysql-count-values-from-table-in-different-columns. You've got to do this with all columns of all tables that you're interested in. Why want you to do this?

Comment: i'm inflating my database with tables of same type but different names. Thus this complicacy in searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat complicated thing to do.  And you really can't do it in one step.  I'll give you something to start with, and you'll have to take it from there:

```
select CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", TABLE_NAME, " WHERE user_id=1;") FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME="user_id";
```

Now this will produce output like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", TABLE_NAME, " WHERE user_id=1;")          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT * FROM table0 WHERE user_id=1;                              |
| SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user_id=1;                              |
```

Now, you want to turn around and execute all of those commands... so do it like this:

```
select CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", TABLE_NAME, " WHERE user_id=1;") FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME="user_id" INTO OUTFILE "some_file_path_and_name";
```

That will give you a text file full of all of the commands you are looking for.

Update---

I missed the "For any column bit.."

```
select CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", TABLE_NAME, " WHERE ", COLUMN_NAME, "='WHATEVER';") FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL INTO OUTFILE 'somepath';
```

Here, we are using the fact that you said you are looking for a string, and all of the string type fields have a collation_name.  Replace WHATEVER with what you are looking for.

Comment: pardon if it sounds silly , but what does user_id=1 here infers to ??
cause when i executed it directly , it gave me an empty set

Comment: What ever it is you are looking for in your database.  You just said "a given string".  You can replace "user_id" in my example with any field name (just be sure to replace it both places in my query).  And replace the "=1" with whatever you are looking for your field to equal.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I missed the bit where you said "In any column".  Let me give you a better answer for that.

Comment: the code you gave is working but when i copy and execute these commands , it says "no database selected"...
just to be sure these commands will return me the records containing the string in one of its columns right ??