# Finding specific value in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

This may sound strange but is it possible to construct a SQL statement that search all the tables in a database for a specific value? I'm testing another person's Drupal(V.7) code and that code uses taxonomy_term_save function to import data in CSV format. I like to find the table where these data are stored. I don't know the field name either. Is it possible? I use MySQL.

Comment: Ask him for the table?! it's all about communication :P

Comment: You can use the [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html) to build such a search. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618727/mysql-query-to-search-a-record-in-complete-database too

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM databasenameHERE WHERE tablenameHERE = 'keyYouAreSearchingForHere'";
```

That is for MySql